# Deep copies of Mutex<> in Rust?

Tags: rust, mutex

I have to generate a large `Vec<Mutex<...>>` at the start of each iteration in my loop which gets mutated in the loop. Since regenerating it each iteration is quite expensive, I am looking for some way to initialize the vec only once, and make *deep* clones of the vector to use in the loop. Of course a simple `.clone()` won't work because the clone will still mutex-guard the same data in memory, not make copies of it. Something along the lines of

```rust
let my_vec = (0..big_usize).map(|_| Mutex::new(..)).collect();

for ... {
    clone = my_vec.deep_clone();
    mutate_clone_safely();
}
```

Comment: Why have a collection of mutexes?

Comment: @DanielA.White I am working with vecs of Arc<Mutex> but I wanted to simplify my example. I want to access vector elements in parallel without locking the entire vec each time. if that's a flawed idea, I'm new to rust my bad.

Comment: Maybe what you need is [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) instead of bare mutexes.

Comment: "I want to access vector elements in parallel" is a little vague. Do you need *read-only* access or *read-write* access? Can you divide the vector into segments instead of granting access at the element level? Can you split the vector up for processing, then reassemble it later, like a *map-reduce* pattern? If writes are sporadic, you can also "accumulate" them into a new copy, then periodically swap between different snapshots of the same data. Lots of ways to avoid contention here.

Comment: @tadman I need rw access at the element level in a par_iter. I am currently using a Vec<Arc<Mutex but I have also considered using an atomic instead. Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: The challenge will be that Rust’s synchronization primitives work with ownership. The vec will be an owner of them, blocking others from owning it

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing with that iterator. Picking the right locking strategy can be tricky, and sometimes you need to re-think your access model to avoid locking.

Comment: @DanielA.White so what I am doing is identical to using a mutex over the entire vec?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why are you guys asking so many questions about OP's structure if its not strange and not the focus of the question? To clone a Mutex, you have to `.lock()` it, clone the inner value, and wrap it in a new Mutex. And to "deep clone" an `Arc`, you have to do that manually as well.

Comment: @kmdreko thank you for the answer, and I am happy to learn about better approaches as well so it's all good.

Comment: @kmdreko Even after providing the answer (because I'm on-board with answering the questions even if they sound fishy, with the assumption that the asker knows what they're doing) the question smells of xy problem. E.g. what exactly is the point of mutexes that are not shared by anyone (since they were created for local use). That, and some other issues, led to commenters asking a seemingly unreasonable number of questions.

Comment: @AmanKP Have you tried [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon)? It is a fantastic library optimized exactly for cases when one need to update slice elements in parallel.
Just look at this [example](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.7.0/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelRefMutIterator.html#tymethod.par_iter_mut).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by kmdreko in the comments, the `deep_clone` you're looking for could be implemented like this:

```
fn deep_clone<T: Clone>(v: &[Mutex<T>]) -> Vec<Mutex<T>> {
    v.iter()
        .map(|el| Mutex::new(el.lock().unwrap().clone()))
        .collect()
}
```

Having provided the literal answer, I still cannot shake off the feeling of xy problem. One might reasonably ask what's the point of mutexes that are not shared by anyone (since they were created for local use). More info might lead to a significantly better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a Vec<f32> but I need to read/write elements in a into_par_iter. Yes it is for local use. Would a rwlock or using atomics be more correct here?

Comment: @AmanKP I do not understand. Do you have `Vec<f32>`, `Vec<Mutex<f32>>`, or `Vec<Arc<Mutex<f32>>>`, as suggested in various other comments? If you're writing elements, then what is the point of the "local" deep clone? I think you should write a new question that describes your _actual_ scenario.